# get the key string of a reference property without using the datastore in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore, referenceproperty

How do you get the key string of a reference property without using the datastore to get the object?

I have 2 datastore objects linked by db.ReferenceProperty:

```
 class Track(db.Model):
   name   = db.StringProperty()
 class Video(db.Model):
   name  = db.StringProperty()
   track = db.ReferenceProperty(Track, collection_name='video-track')
```

This makes it easy get the linked track from a given video:

```
 video = Video.get(a_video_key_string)
 track = video.track
```

And I can store these into memcache for quick access later:

```
 memcache.add(str(video.key()), video)
 memcache.add(str(track.key()), track)
```

Now I can get a video or track from memcache:

```
 video = memcache.get(a_video_key_string)
 track = memcache.get(str(video.track.key()))
```

However, this generates a datastore request for the track, even though I dont want it to. Specifically, the video.track request automatically calls the datastore to get the Track object and then calls key() to determine the key string.

I want to get the key value from the linked ReferenceProperty without actually instantiating a Track object. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: You can use `KeyProperty` instead of `ReferenceProperty`. That way you get only the Key of the entity. If you need to load the entity, you get it by the key directly.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned you could change the property to be a KeyProperty, alternately you could use property.get_value_for_datastore(obj) method of a property to get the key without resolving the object.

See docs  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass#Property_get_value_for_datastore

Normally you would use it to get the key using something like

key = myclass.some_property.get_value_for_datastore(some_obj)

So in your case from your examples

track_key = Video.track.get_value_for_datastore(video)

Cheers